# simple HTML <input> name=?

Tags: html

What is the normal name = for both company name and job title?
incase they have already filled that out somewhere and they have autofill
enabled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no standard for this. You can look at other, popular sites though and see what they use

Comment: hmm they should so make a standard.. well i will just go by linkin

Comment: @VictorWeng: Who is "they"?  The job title naming standards board?  There is no "they" in this case.  You could define a standard yourself, even publish it.  But there isn't much incentive for anybody else to follow it.

Comment: w3 can set some standards made for autofill functions its not that bad imo

Comment: a lot of autofill software seems to take an intelligent guess if there's something close, so just 'name' and 'company' would probably work in most cases, but as others have said there's no standard.